# Recursively find and replace strings in SunOS 5.10

Tags: unix, find, sunos

What would be a UNIX command for recursively finding and replacing strings in text files on a SunOS 5.10 machine?

Ex:

I want to replace a string `SIR01111` with `SIR02222` in files from my current directory, recursively.

Comment: What shell are you using?

Comment: http://theunixshell.blogspot.com/2012/12/find-and-replace-string-in-all-files.html

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -name "*.txt"|xargs perl -pi -e 's/SIR01111/SIR02222/g'
```